# How to use JSON_REMOVE with several rows from a subquery?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a table with json-column in the column `data` and a table with keys to delete from the first table. MySQL 5.7.

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key10": "value10", "key100": "value100"} |
| 20 | {"key1": "value1", "key18": "value18", "key150": "value150"} |
| 57 | {"key5": "value5", "key10": "value10"} |

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | key1 | value1 |
| 18 | key2 | value2 |
| 30 | key150 | value150 |

I want to delete all elements with keys from the second table.
I tried `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` but `JSON_REMOVE()` requires the "path[, path]"-structure with keys according to [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove).

```
UPDATE `table1` as `t1`
SET `t1`.`data` =  JSON_REMOVE(`t1`.`data`, (
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(`key`)
    FROM `table2` as `t2`
    )
);
```

I haven't found examples or docs about json paths from subquery rows.
How can I transform rows or maybe array values from returned rows to correct paths?

A result I expect after the query:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"key10": "value10", "key100": "value100"} |
| 20 | {"key18": "value18"} |
| 57 | {"key5": "value5", "key10": "value10"} |

Answer (score 1):

You could prepare a query to be executed. The query could be dynamically created.

In this case you'll need to create this query to update the table (I call it `json_stuff`):

```sql
UPDATE json_stuff
   SET jsons = JSON_REMOVE(jsons, '$.key1','$.key2','$.key150')
```

Which can be dynamically created and put into a variable using:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE json_stuff SET jsons = JSON_REMOVE(jsons, ",
              GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'$.',keyname,'\'')),
              ")")
  INTO @sql_delete_string
  FROM delete_stuff
```

..where `delete_stuff` is your table containing the keys to be removed.

You can then execute it using this procedure with `call execute_immediate(@sql_delete_string)`:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE execute_immediate(IN query MEDIUMTEXT)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    SET @q = query;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Note: this procedure has been taken from [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE MySQL](https://www.jamescoyle.net/tag/procedure)

---

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d53956f276db7ed98b6e49f3f456e83a)